# ndarray: Iterate over shuffled rows

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, permutation

I am looking for an efficient way to iterate over a permutation of the rows in a two-dimensional array in `ndarray`. I do not need to mutate or keep the permuted array around, so I want to avoid a copy.

That is, I want to do the following, except [`select`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.select) allocates an unnecessary array:

```
use ndarray::{Axis, Array}; // 0.13.1
use rand::seq::SliceRandom; // 0.7.3
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn main() {
    let array = Array::from_iter(0..15).into_shape((5, 3)).unwrap();
    println!("Before shuffling rows:\n{}", array);
    
    let mut permutation: Vec<usize> = (0..array.nrows()).collect();
    permutation.shuffle(&mut rand::thread_rng());
    let permuted = array.select(Axis(0), &permutation);
    
    for (i, row) in permuted.axis_iter(Axis(0)).enumerate() {
        println!("Row number {} is {}!", i, row);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20ndarray%3A%3A%7BAxis%2C%20Array%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%200.13.1%0Ause%20rand%3A%3Aseq%3A%3ASliceRandom%3B%20%2F%2F%200.7.3%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aiter%3A%3AFromIterator%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20array%20%3D%20Array%3A%3Afrom_iter(0..15).into_shape((5%2C%203)).unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22Before%20shuffling%20rows%3A%5Cn%7B%7D%22%2C%20array)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20permutation%3A%20Vec%3Cusize%3E%20%3D%20(0..array.nrows()).collect()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20permutation.shuffle(%26mut%20rand%3A%3Athread_rng())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20permuted%20%3D%20array.select(Axis(0)%2C%20%26permutation)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(i%2C%20row)%20in%20permuted.axis_iter(Axis(0)).enumerate()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Row%20number%20%7B%7D%20is%20%7B%7D!%22%2C%20i%2C%20row)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

I am aware that the `ndarray` Github page includes an [example](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/blob/master/examples/sort-axis.rs) of something similar, but it involves a block of unsafe code that I do not understand and therefore prefer not to adapt to my own use case.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious answer that I missed, using [index_axis](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.index_axis):

```
use ndarray::{Axis, Array}; // 0.13.1
use rand::seq::SliceRandom; // 0.7.3
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn main() {
    let array = Array::from_iter(0..15).into_shape((5, 3)).unwrap();
    println!("Before shuffling rows:\n{}", array);
    
    let mut permutation: Vec<usize> = (0..array.nrows()).collect();
    permutation.shuffle(&mut rand::thread_rng());
    
    for i in permutation.iter() {
        let row = array.index_axis(Axis(0), *i);
        println!("Row number {} is {}!", i, row);
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are better ways of doing this, however, and I'm still interested to see them.